# redux practice for 2 frequent challenges

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to learn a good practice from others,
please share how you do this :

Task:
suppose there are 2 reducer: 
boy : "Tom",  girl : "Mary"

a function `swap()` is going to swap those 2 values,
such as boy : "Mary",  girl : "Tom"

Here is the plan :

dispatch 2 action :

`{type: BOY_EDIT, value: "Mary"}`,
`{type: GIRL_EDIT, value: "Tom"}`

and the cons is:

1. reducer can not read other reducers' value, and you need to pass them through actions
2. there are two actions for two reducer, as someone said don't mess two reducer by one action which will cause maintainability reducing

what do you think?  A easy and good way to solve these 2 frequent challenges ?

Ps: redux-saga `select()` may be a good solution ?

#

Addition:

Sorry for making unclear question,
I understand that above scenario can solved by combining reducers as 1
But my assumption is NOT combining them

This is because I just simplify the scenario above
And the real situationis, some cases you need to do some operation in reducer and depend on other reducers' value.

I would like to know other's practices on facing this challenge

Answer (score 1):

Map both girl and boy to the same container, and dispatch a single action. I don't see why this is bad practice. 
On the other hand, creating two actions for this is a bad practice, since after 2 years you will need to change your code, forget that the two actions are tied together, and change only one.

If I am not wrong, redux itself dispatches a single action when it starts, something called INIT or something similar, I don't have a running system in front of me now, that is dispatched to all reducers...
I also use INIT actions of my own, for example, when a user logs out of the application, to clear her/his data.

Comment: Combining to 1 container - Sure,  this is a good idea,  but it may not when the situation become complicated.  You sure can combine the whole app state as 1 reducer,  but I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Moreover, if in two reducers, you still can not avoid forget to change the code even you use 1 action. In fact, it will be more forgettable if you use 1 action. You may see, action `SWAP`, and find that reducer `boy` has handle it,  but forget `girl`.

Comment: beside,  some case may suitable to use 1 action,  such as `LOGOUT`, and all reducer will clean all data and return INITIAL_STATE

Comment: Regarding 1st comment: I didn't say one reducer :) Regarding 2nd comment: right, but since the single action handles the entire swap, less chances for an error... Agree with the 3rd one, that's what I meant to write :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a single reducer say an object which has both boy and girl properties and a single action say ‘SWAP’ to swap the property values.

Initialise the reducer with an initialValue so that default state is created.

Within SWAP action

```
return {boy: state.girl, girl: state.boy}
```

Comment: Sure, and thanks for sharing. How about if we limited as the assumption in my additional edit ?

Comment: A reducer must only modify the state associated to it. So if an action has to update two properties of an object in state, that action should reside in the parent reducer, not in individual reducers

Comment: So you may perfer 1 big reducer which save an object to store all information in an app ?

Comment: No. For maintainability it’s preferable to compose  reducers into multiple. But an action that need access to two redux store properties should be written at first common parent level.